# My Next.js installation is abnormal, what is wrong and how can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, next.js, tailwind-css

I am new specifically to Next.js and I'm struggling to figure out why I'm unable to reach my second page, called auth.js (using localhost:3000/auth). I have a button in my "page.js", which was installed as my "index.js" ([Whole Directory](https://i.imgur.com/VR4Mao2.png)), and the button should href to /auth:

```
<li>
    <Link href="/auth"><p className="h-8 w-17 px-3 py-1 hover: text-xl font-burtons text-green-700 bg-gray-900">Login</p></Link>
</li>
```

but it's giving me a 404 error. I also have a reference here to my Auth code:

```
import FirebaseAuth from "../components/auth/FirebaseAuth";

export default function Auth() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <FirebaseAuth />
                <p><a href="/">Go Home</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I have looked up everything I can, and everything points to the fact that I need to have, in my directory (portfolio for example), the folders called public, components, pages, and styles. Everything else should be in the same root folder, portfolio, as the rest of them. I tried moving things around, but next.js will ONLY run the dev server, npm run dev, when the pages.js (my index.js) is in the src/app folder and no where else. I attempted having auth.js in the /src/app folder, as well as moving it to the /src/app/pages folder. Nothing really seems to allow me to access localhost:3000/auth, and it gives me the 404 regardless.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, [do not require the reader to use links to external information](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/more-advice#dont-require-external-and-off-site-resources). Everything should be in the question itself. If you have code, copy and paste it into the question so it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Comment: But you have only 1 page in `pages` directory (as per the image you have provided). Move your main/index page (and every other pages) into the `pages` directory.

Answer (score 1):

Routing with the app directory is controlled via the folders inside of it. The UI for a particular route is defined by a page.jsx file inside of the folder. If you are using APP folder your structure should look like:

`app/auth/page.jsx`

If you are using pages directory it should be:

`pages/auth.jsx`